# create setup wizard by visual studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, .net-3.5

I have to do four things install .net framework 3.5 ,install SQL Server 2005 and run my sql script on the server and create the database and install my application how to do it in a single setup project using visual studio 2008/2010

Comment: Did it help you or do you need some further informations ?

Comment: i need more information cause i never create any setup.

Comment: If you had read the articel and tried something where you are now stuck on, than please update your question which problems you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the .net Framework you can add `Prerequisites` in your Setup Project. You can find the Prerequisites by right clicking on your Project and choose Properties.

When you want to run a SQL Script during installation you need a `Custom Action`. There is a nice Walkthrough on MSDN which explaines how to [use a custom Action to Create a Database During Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)